# Is there a range(..) function in Python2.7 that returns a generator instead of a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, generator

I am planning to write this function to yield all integers between two numbers, just like python3 `range` class.

I already wrote this function like this:

```
def gen_numbers(start,end):
    counter = start
    while counter <= end:
        yield counter
        counter += 1
```

but if any built-in function already exists, tell me to use it!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, [xrange](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange) returns an [xrange object](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-xrange). Does it have to be specifically a generator?